# Why Cannot register SQL driver in JTesterDataSource?

Tags: java, jtest

I write a test class for testing my code.
My database configuration is in jtester.properties, and the file as follow:

```
 database.type=MYSQL
 database.url=jdbc:mysql://xxxx:3311/ae_fc_00
 database.userName=xxxx
 database.password=xxxx
 database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I'm sure the username and url and password is correct. But When I run test, I got the error as follow:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot register SQL driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.jtester.module.database.JTesterDataSource.registerDriver(JTesterDataSource.java:175)
    at org.jtester.module.database.JTesterDataSource.createDataSource(JTesterDataSource.java:49)
    at org.jtester.module.database.JTesterDataSource.<init>(JTesterDataSource.java:44)
    at org.jtester.module.database.environment.AbstractDBEnvironment.setDataSource(AbstractDBEnvironment.java:68)
    at org.jtester.module.database.environment.DBEnvironmentFactory.getDBEnvironment(DBEnvironmentFactory.java:156)
    at org.jtester.module.database.environment.DBEnvironmentFactory.getDBEnvironment(DBEnvironmentFactory.java:93)
    at org.jtester.module.database.environment.DBEnvironmentFactory.getCurrentDBEnvironment(DBEnvironmentFactory.java:192)
    at org.jtester.core.context.TransactionManager.startTransaction(TransactionManager.java:47)
    at com.alibaba.qa.qtester.module.DatabaseModule$DatabaseTestListener.beforeMethodRunning(DatabaseModule.java:141)
    at org.jtester.module.core.CoreModule$CoreModuleListener.beforeMethodRunning(CoreModule.java:126)
    at org.jtester.core.ListenerExecutor.executeBeforeMethodRunningEvents(ListenerExecutor.java:73)
    at com.alibaba.qa.qtester.unitils.QTesterTestNG.run(QTesterTestNG.java:228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178)
```

Please help me... My jtester version is 1.1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not include mysql driver in class path of your project.

If it's a maven project, add following config in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, download driver file [from here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar) and include it in your project

Comment: Yes, you are right. I add the dependency to my pom.xml, all things is correct.